# How can i identify media uploaded to my website that is not being used anywhere anymore?

Tags: images, uploads, media

At the time of development i upload a lot of images on the site. Over the time, i may need to tweak it quality or resolution, so mostly i upload the images with same name. So by the end of the development, i have a lot of similar images, only 1 of them being in use somewhere. How can i identify the unused ones and delete them from my server?

Answer (score 1):

You can go into your media library to view all your attachments. There is an unattached option at the top that shows you media that isn't connected to any pages or posts. You can then select them for deletion.

Comment: Your answer is correct for posts and pages but sadly there are other instances where media in use may show as unattached. Some plugins and themes for example may be using images shown as unattached in the media library.

Comment: And i need to delete unused images on a live website. So cannot take any chances here.

Comment: Always run a backup!